# Server connections refused when hostname used, works fine with IP

Tags: networking, dns, iptables, raspbian, hostname

Hope someone can help. I've run a local server for a while on a Rapberry Pi 3b (Raspbian Buster) that includes a PBX server, DNSmasq and local webserver.

I recently upgraded to a Pi4 and performed a fresh install of all systems.

I now seem to have an issue that I'm guessing is to do with the firewall.

Previously I set up additional names in Dnsmasq that resolved to the same machine using:

```
address=/servername/server_alias/127.0.0.1
```

And everything was fine. However on the new system, if I attempt to access the web server via http://server_name or http://server_alias, the connection is refused.

Using the server IP is accepted and the pages load.

I do have fail2ban installed and have disabled it. I am pretty green with IPtables but as far as I can tell, the rules automatically set up as part of the PBX install should be enabling the system to function correctly.

Connections from 127.0.0.1/8 and 192.168.0.0/16 are permitted.

I have system hostname set up per above and also reflected in my /etc/hosts.

Any guidance on what the issue could be or what other output I should try to look at would be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance